# How can I parse this JSON data using str.replace?

Tags: python, string, replace, format, tuples

**UPDATE**

Code:

```
print('\n //// jsonData5 at the beginning:\n')
print(reply)
print(reply.__class__)

string2 = ''
string2 = reply.replace("\\", "")

print('\n //// string2:\n')
print(string2)

string1 = ''
for index, item in enumerate(res.decode()):
    string1 = string1 + item
    #string = string + item.decode()

string1 = string1.replace("'", "")
string1 = string1.replace("/", "")

print(string1)
jsonData6 = json.loads(string1)
jsonData8 = json.loads(string2)
res_loaded = jsonData8['res']
print('\n //// resloaded\n')
print(res_loaded['node'])

print('\n //// jsonData6[res]\n')
pprint(jsonData6)
print('\n //// jsonData5[res]\n')
pprint(jsonData5)
print('\n //// jsonData8[res]\n')
pprint(jsonData8['res']['node'])
```

Output:

```
//// jsonData5 at the beginning:

{"length": 106, "res": "{\"message\": \"New Block Forged\", \"index\": 106, \"transactions\": [{\"sender\": \"0\", \"recipient\": \"4a77509b1ca041d4b41e7983b6292691\", \"amount\": 1}], \"proof\": 299671, \"previous_hash\": \"3a83c09446911419318d671abb3de3523e32bc68dfea7b1a78eb9c459303c0ae\", \"node\": \"4a77509b1ca041d4b41e7983b6292691\"}"}
<class 'str'>

 //// string2:

{"length": 106, "res": "{"message": "New Block Forged", "index": 106, "transactions": [{"sender": "0", "recipient": "4a77509b1ca041d4b41e7983b6292691", "amount": 1}], "proof": 299671, "previous_hash": "3a83c09446911419318d671abb3de3523e32bc68dfea7b1a78eb9c459303c0ae", "node": "4a77509b1ca041d4b41e7983b6292691"}"}
{"message": "New Block Forged", "index": 112, "transactions": [{"sender": "0", "recipient": "433fc033fdb844aca7d28f93d26550af", "amount": 1}], "proof": 4940, "previous_hash": "86194415a7350a765a8917e2783872ce104f5724fd82ec3647ad8664147e1cc6", "node": "433fc033fdb844aca7d28f93d26550af"}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alicep2p.py", line 121, in <module>
    jsonData8 = json.loads(string2)
  File "/home/pi/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/home/pi/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/home/pi/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 27 (char 26)
```

### This is a different error then the one I was seeing, it wont load it.

I have this code:

```
print('\n //// jsonData5 at the beginning:\n')
pprint(reply)
print(reply.__class__)

string2 = ''
string2 = reply.replace("'", "")
string2 = string2.replace('/', "")
string2 = string2.replace('(', "")
string2 = string2.replace(')', "")

print('\n //// string2:\n')
pprint(string2)
```

The console output is:

```
//// jsonData5 at the beginning:

('{"length": 48, "res": "{\\"message\\": \\"New Block Forged\\", \\"index\\": '
 '48, \\"transactions\\": [{\\"sender\\": \\"0\\", \\"recipient\\": '
 '\\"39ca48e4074e41c29374a4a59b1e0481\\", \\"amount\\": 1}], \\"proof\\": '
 '550305, \\"previous_hash\\": '
 '\\"cc64a8b99bc7be84261919159d456a19b204b3694388fe3fe203b0fc3c2d57d7\\", '
 '\\"node\\": \\"39ca48e4074e41c29374a4a59b1e0481\\"}"}')
<class 'str'>

//// string2:

('{"length": 48, "res": "{\\"message\\": \\"New Block Forged\\", \\"index\\": '
 '48, \\"transactions\\": [{\\"sender\\": \\"0\\", \\"recipient\\": '
 '\\"39ca48e4074e41c29374a4a59b1e0481\\", \\"amount\\": 1}], \\"proof\\": '
 '550305, \\"previous_hash\\": '
 '\\"cc64a8b99bc7be84261919159d456a19b204b3694388fe3fe203b0fc3c2d57d7\\", '
 '\\"node\\": \\"39ca48e4074e41c29374a4a59b1e0481\\"}"}')
```

Seemingly nothing happens to the string - even though I change it with the `replace()` function - I am new to python - what am I doing wrong? Or how do I turn the output into something I can access?

Comment: It looks like your replacements are actually working, it's just that you don't have any `'`, `/`, `(`, or `)` in the original string. Those characters that you see are just the result of the `pprint` method displaying the string in your console. The actual data begins at the first `{` in your console and ends at the last `}`.

Comment: thanks...so is it a string that I should be able to use with `json.loads()`? and what about the escape characters? those are pprint too?

Comment: They're working, you're just confused by the output of `pprint()`. Try `print(string2)` and you'll see that everything's OK.

Comment: @ewizard it will work with `json.loads` however you will find that the resulting dictionary will have more json strings in it such as the value for `"res"` being a json string.

Comment: im updating my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to parse JSON data? Use the [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) package.

```
>>> import json
>>> dict = json.loads('{"x":"y"}')
{u'x': u'y'}
>>>> json.dumps(dict)
'{"x": "y"}'
```

In your example, your data is double encoded, so you need to parse it twice:

```
import json
data = '{"length": 48, "res": "{\\"message\\": \\"New Block Forged\\", \\"index\\": 48, \\"transactions\\": [{\\"sender\\": \\"0\\", \\"recipient\\": \\"39ca48e4074e41c29374a4a59b1e0481\\", \\"amount\\": 1}], \\"proof\\": 550305, \\"previous_hash\\": \\"cc64a8b99bc7be84261919159d456a19b204b3694388fe3fe203b0fc3c2d57d7\\", \\"node\\": \\"39ca48e4074e41c29374a4a59b1e0481\\"}"}'
json.loads(json.loads(data)['res'])
```

Are you just trying to [replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) specific characters?

```
>>> x = 'abca'
>>> print(x.replace('a', 'e'))
ebce
```

If you are getting confused by `pprint` and other escape characters, write it out to a file as plain bytes:

```
with open('out.dat', 'w') as f:
    f.write(my_string)
```

Comment: i was trying to remove what pprint was adding not knowing it was pprint

Comment: i need to replace the escape characters `{"length": 14, "res": "{\"message\": \"New Block Forged\", \"index\": 14, \"transactions\": [{\"sender\": \"0\", \"recipient\": \"4b9a0aa5bcec492db0fca93c4485258c\", \"amount\": 1}], \"proof\": 702791, \"previous_hash\": \"9e814c63ad3ae8094748778cd4c0921c252b2ee6a9c35cefb0767592b0718f75\", \"node\": \"4b9a0aa5bcec492db0fca93c4485258c\"}"}` - those should have been taken out by my replace oh wait nm i used the wrong slash :)

Comment: ah - your string is "double encoded" in JSON. I updated my answer to show you how to load it twice

Comment: hmmm ok ill try it...i think i have tried this before...i am just having trouble turning this into a json object

Comment: how am i parsing it twice?

Comment: like so: `json.loads(json.loads(reply)['res'])`

Comment: oh i was actually doing that already...one sec;...oh wait not loads twice i dont think

Comment: im getting `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'`